# How to split a file into different arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, file

I'm reading a file and I need to split it into different arrays. The file is styled like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and I need to create an array that would be `[1, 4, 7]` and then a different array that would be `[2,5,8]` and so on. I'm not too sure how to do this. I saw I there was the `split()` command but I don't really know how to switch which array is being appended.

Comment: Call `split()` on each line of the file after opening it.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your attempt, even it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Use list(my_lst[:,n])

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily use pandas `DataFrame` object like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "numbers.txt"  # Change this to your file path
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=' ', header=None)
```

Now if you would `print(df)` you could see each column separately and can access it with `iloc[:, i]` like this:

```
first_col = df.iloc[:, 0]
second_col = df.iloc[:, 1]
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a text file *values.txt* structured as you described, you can do the following:

```
with open("./values.txt", "r") as f:
    l = f.readlines() # read the initial list from file

    l_2d = [[int(i) for i in item.strip().split()] for item in l]
    l_2d_t = [list(x) for x in zip(*l_2d)] # get the transpose

    print(l_2d_t) # Prints [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use the `hsplit()` function to manipulate your data.

numpy.hsplit(ary, indices_or_sections)

take a look at this: https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/manipulation/hsplit.php

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)
for i in range(len(data[0])):
    print(list(data[:,i]))
```

Comment: Why the votedown? It Does exacly what you whant

Comment: I cannot speak for the person who down voted. I also haven't examined your code. But Quality Answers include an explanation, for the OP, and for future visitors to learn from, so they can apply this knowledge to their own coding issues. You can skim topics in StackOverflow.com/help for other advice. Finally, if there are any caveats, ie cases where your code might not work, it's good to notate that. Supplementary links to documentation are also sometimes helpful for people to look up, & verify details.

Comment: You are right, i Will and explanation to the answer. Good comment, upvote!